# Input radio buttonset safari bug?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Here is link: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VrAqw/4/)

I use jquery  1.8 and jquery ui 1.8.23

When I try to zoom it in Safari, input round button appears in the result panels corner. How can I hide it?

Thank you.

Comment: Inspected the fiddle in Firefox via `Ctr+Shift+i` shortcut. In `jQueryUI.css` on line 10 there is invalid definition: `.ui-helper-hidden-accessible { left: -99999999px; }` , change it to: `.ui-helper-hidden-accessible { left: -99999px; }` or redefine with the `!improtant` flag. Yes I guess it's really a bug in Safari, they replace that big negative (and incorrect) offset to zero, instead of some big negative (boundary) integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can add this style (not sure if this is perfect but you may give it a try)

```
.ui-helper-hidden-accessible{
    display:none;
}​
```

But make sure it's submitting properly, I've tested it in `safari`.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VrAqw/5/).